# Can Cygwin access Windows Hidden Shares?

Tags: cygwin

Is there any way to access a Windows "hidden share" from Cygwin?

I've tried:

```
cd //server/c$
cd //server/c'$'
cd //server/'c$'
cd //server/c\$
```

Cygwin doesn't like the '$'.

EDIT: I have also tried mounting a drive to the network share and accessing that from Cygwin (as djondal suggests below), but no joy.  For a drive mapped to Z:, /cygdrive/z is not recognized, even after mounting it in cygwin (mount Z: /cygdrive/z)

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try by mapping a network drive Z: to //server/ and then the letter you choose will be accessible in /cygdrive/z/

Comment: I had also tried that (will edit OP to reflect).  The problem I ran into was Cygwin did not recognize /cygdrive/z even after trying to mount it (mount Z: /cygdrive/z)

Comment: Do not try to mount it. Just do as explained here (for mapping the drive) http://compnetworking.about.com/od/windowsxpnetworking/ht/mapnetworkdrive.htm or http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308582 and do not try to mount with cygwin. Then reboot your machine and it should work.

Answer (score 2):

```
ls //HOSTID/c$/"documents and settings"
```

The above works fine for me in cygwin under win7